# How to track loss and accuracy in PyTorch?

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, confusion-matrix

I have made model and it is working fine for the MNIST dataset but further in the assignment it says to track loss and accuracy of the model, which I do not know how to do it. I have also written some code for that also but not sure if its right or not.

Train model. (Working great)

```
for epoch in range(epochs):
   for i, (images, labels) in enumerate(train_dataloader):

   optimizer.zero_grad()

   y_pred = model(images)

   loss = loss_function(y_pred, labels)

   loss.backward()
    
   optimizer.step()
```

Track loss:

```
def train(dataloader, optimizer, model, loss_fn, device, master_bar):
""" method to train the model """
    epoch_loss = []
    epoch_correct, epoch_total = 0, 0

    for x, y in fastprogress.progress_bar(dataloader, parent=master_bar):
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        model.train()

        # Forward pass
        outputs = model(images)

        # For calculating the accuracy, save the number of correctly classified images and the 
          total number
        _, predicted = torch.max(outputs.data, 1)
        epoch_total += labels.size(0)
    
        #epoch_correct += predicted.eq(labels).sum().item()
        if torch.cuda.is_available():
            epoch_correct += (predicted.cpu() == labels.cpu()).sum()
        else:
            epoch_correct += (predicted == labels).sum()

        # Compute loss
        loss = loss_function(y_pred, labels)

        # Backward pass
        loss.backward()

        # For plotting the train loss, save it for each sample
          epoch_loss.append(train_loss)

        # Return the mean loss and the accuracy of this epoch
     return train_loss / len(train_dataloader), 100 * epoch_correct.item() / epoch_total
```

Validation track

```
def validate(dataloader, model, loss_fn, device, master_bar):
    """ method to compute the metrics on the validation set """
    epoch_loss = []
    epoch_correct, epoch_total = 0, 0
    confusion_matrix = torch.zeros(10, 10)    

    model.eval()
    with torch.no_grad():
    for x, y in fastprogress.progress_bar(dataloader, parent=master_bar):
        # make a prediction on validation set
        prediction = model(images)

        # For calculating the accuracy, save the number of correctly classified images and the 
          total number

        _, predicted = torch.max(outputs.data, 1)
        epoch_total += labels.size(0)

        if torch.cuda.is_available():
          epoch_correct += (predicted.cpu() == labels.cpu()).sum()
        else:
          epoch_correct += (predicted == labels).sum()
          
        # Fill values into confusion matrix

        # Compute loss
        loss = loss_function(y_pred, labels)

        # For plotting the train loss, save it

# Return the mean loss, the accuracy and the confusion matrix
return
```

I want to know that whatever I have written in `def train` and in `def validate` is correct or not? and also I am missing some code to write which I am not able to think how to write. Can anybody look at the code and share suggestions?